# What regex can I use to capture groups from this string?

Tags: python, regex

Assume the following strings:

- `A01B100`
- `A01.B100`
- `A01`
- `A01............................B100` ( whatever between A and B )

The thing is, the numbers should be `\d+`, and in all of the strings A will always be present, while B may not. A will always be followed by one or more digits, and so will B, if present. What regex could I use to capture A and B's digit?

I have the following regex:

```
(A(\d+)).*?(B?(\d+)?)
```

but this only works for the first and the third case.

Comment: you need to escape the dot. that's all. `(A(\d+))\.*?(B?(\d+)?)`

Comment: I think the dots in the test cases were placeholders, not literal dots?

Comment: they were literal dots, but there can be any char in between. Sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Must `A` precede `B`? Assuming yes.
- Can `B` appear more than once? Assuming no.
- Can `B` appear except as part of a `B`-number group? Assuming no.

Then,

```
A\d+.*?(B\d+)?
```

using the lazy .*? or

```
A\d+[^B]*(B\d+)?
```

which is more efficient but requires that `B` be a single character.

EDIT: Upon further reflection, I have parenthesized the patterns in a less-than-perfect way. The following patterns should require fewer assumptions:

```
A\d+(.*?B\d+)?
a\d+([^B]*B\d+)?
```

Comment: What about if the string is A01---Bambam-B90?

Comment: I assumed that B cannot appear except as part of a B-number group. (Additionally, I am not clear on whether B is a single character 'B' or an abbreviation for another pattern.) If either of my assumptions here are untrue, then the [^B] pattern will fail. The .*? pattern should still work, though, unless I'm misunderstanding the interaction of the greedy ? and lazy *? operators.

Comment: I've slightly modified the patterns to clearly express the proper interaction of the lazy and greedy operators.

Comment: I believe you want the greedy version, ".*", if you assume that the B-number group must come at the end of a line.  The lazy .*? will stop at the first "B" character it encounters, whereas the greedy .* will go to the last "B" on the line (the one you want).

Comment: The pattern with correct groupings (you'll want groups \1 and \3: A(\d+).*(B(\d+))?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?ms)^A(\d+)(?:[^\n\r]*B(\d+))?$
```

Assuming one string per line:

- the [^\n\r]* is a non-greedy match for any characters (except newlines) after Axx, meaing it could gobble an intermediate Byy before the last B:

  A01...B01...B23

would be matched, with 01 and 23 detected.

Comment: I think it should be without ^ and $, because A and B can be inside another string.

Answer (score 0):

```
A\d+.*(B\d+)?
```

OK, so that provides something which passes all test cases...
BUT it has some false positives.

```
A\d+(.*B\d+)?
```

It seems other characters should only appear if B(whatever) is after them, so use the above instead.

```
#perl test case hackup
@array = ('A01B100', 'A01.B100', 'A01', 'A01............................B100', 'A01FAIL', 'NEVER');
for (@array) {
print "$_\n" if $_ =~ /^A\d+(.*B\d+)?$/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
m = re.match(r"A(?P<d1>\d+)\.*(B(?P<d2>\d+))?", "A01.B100")
print m.groupdict()
```